# Measure a unknown battery?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I have a physics exercise that goes:

> Given resistances $\mathrm{R_1 = 5 \Omega}$ , $\mathrm{R_2 = 11\Omega}$ and corresponding currents $\mathrm{I_1 = 0,5A}$ and $\mathrm{I_2=0,25A}$ connected with a battery, find the voltage/(open-circuit voltage) and the output impendance (inner resistance of the battery)

**My question(s) :**

> When calculating the voltage with $\mathrm{R=V/I}$ I get
>
> $\mathrm{V_1=R_1\times I_1=5 \Omega \times 0.5A  =2.5V}$
>
> $\mathrm{V_2=R_2 \times I_2=11 \Omega \times 0.25A=2.75V}$

1. Shouldn't the two voltages be the same? What is the voltage of the battery?
2. How do you calculate the output impendance (inner resistance of the battery)?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short-term behavior of most real batteries can be closely modeled by a [*Thévenin equivalent network*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem). That is, by an [ideal voltage source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_source) in series with a resistor. The resistor represents what is commonly known as the "internal resistance" of the battery. And, when no current is allowed to flow, then the terminal voltage of the Thévenin circuit is the same as the source voltage. (a.k.a., the "open circuit voltage" of the battery.)

Your assignment most likely is to assume that "battery" means Thévenin source, and to solve for the unknown "internal resistance" and the unknown "open circuit voltage."

> How do you calculate the ...inner resistance of the battery?

You could use a graphical method to find the open-circuit voltage: Plot two points on a graph of voltage vs. current. One point for $I_1$, and one for $I_2$. You already have used Ohm's law and the known values of $R_1$ and $R_2$ to find the voltage at those two points, as described in your question, above.

Now, draw a straight line through the two points (You can do that because the behavior of ideal resistors is [*linear*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation). Extend the line to where $I=0$, and that should tell you the open-circuit voltage.

Seeing the graph should trigger enough memory of high-school math for you to figure out how to solve the problem algebraically and get an exact answer.

Once you have an exact value for the open circuit voltage, Knowing the difference between that and the voltage at either $I_1$ or $I_2$ will give you the voltage "dropped" by the unknown internal resistance. Then it's just a matter of using Ohm's law again, to find the unknown resistance value.